# Statistical analysis techniques for pre and post repeated measures

Tags: anova, t-test, repeated-measures, ancova

I am trying to understand which is the appropriate statistical technique to use for the below experimental design:

Design: I have two groups - an intervention group (that took an action, eg increased their savings %) and a control group (that took no action). I am currently looking at the average savings rates for these two group 1 month,  3 months and 6 months before and after a reference date(reference date is action date for intervention group and a randomly selected date for control group). I want to be able to determine if the difference between the two groups is significant and the confidence interval for it using a statistical technique

Based on my research I have read the below techniques can be used for the kind of experimental design I am working on:

1. Repeated measures ANOVA - can I use a +/-1month, +/-3month, +/-6month time duration for this test?
2. ANCOVA
3. Linear Mixed Models
4. t-test

It is my first time trying to use a statistical technique for this kind of design. Any thoughts on which technique is most suitable for this design will be helpful

Comment: Linear Mixed Model